# IE9: canvas.toDataURL SECURITY_ERR

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

I am trying to convert facebook image to base64, but ***FileReader*** will not work on IE9, so i decided to use canvas.

Anyway, using canvas also generate an issue:

> SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: SECURITY_ERR (18)

And this is my code:

```
var url="http://graph.facebook.com/1420060541/picture?width=320&height=320";
 var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 img = new Image;

 img.onload = function () {
  canvas.height = img.height;
  canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
  console.log(dataURL);
  canvas = null;
};
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
img.src = url;
```

Comment: IE team didn't implemented the `crossorigin` attribute before the 11th version of their "only has the name" *browser*. So you're screwed. Possible workaround : server proxy on the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

Seems facebook does have the cross origin header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*"`allowing anyone to see the images. 
If you tried to load an image forgetting to add `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');` adding it the second time will fail because the cached image is interfering with the request headers. Empty the cache and send the request again with `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');` that may fix your problem.

Cross domain error. There is no solution. Images must be from the same domain so you need to move the image to your domain, if you have one. Or set up a server on your machine and move the image to a directory on that. 
IF your domain is `www.privateDomain.com` then only images from `privateDomain` can be accessed via `toDataURL`
If you are just using your hard drive, ie your page url starts with `file:///` you can not access any image via toDataURL.

There are exceptions because some servers send headers with their images that allow cross domain access. One source of such images is wiki commons. There are others but you will have to search for them.

The other solution is to turn off network security on the browser (I don't know how on IE) but that will leave your browser open to attacks.

Its sad that we cant trust even images, but that is the way it is.

Comment: Actually, at least from their graph API, FB images are served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` headers, so setting the `crossorigin` attribute of the `<img>` to `'anonymous'` could have worked, if IE implemented this feature...

Comment: Just tried an image from my friends list and it threw Tained. But found a solution.

Comment: So did this changed in the last two weeks ? or are you talking about non-graph FB images, like I did in the first version of my comment?

Comment: @Kaiido Cached images will fail despite the Origin request headers set correctly. Emptying the cache fixes the problem. And yes FB

Comment: But OP's problem was specific to IE9, where there is no `crossorigin` attribute anyway.

Comment: Well if IE cant set the origin header then its time for him grab a shovel and bury it. To paraphrase Douglas Crockford. "IE must die... "